# Overlapping issue on activity page

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

**The tab is overlapping in the activity page.**

Actually, I earned a new badge and when I go to grab it. I found this glitch. The activity tabs are overlapped on congratulation badge area.

**[image: Please see the attached screenshot.]**